# How can I deploy my entire project on Google Cloud Run using a Docker Compose YAML file?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, dockerfile, google-cloud-run

How can I deploy my entire project on Google Cloud Run using a Docker Compose YAML file?

Comment: You can't. Docker Compose yaml file is designed for bering run on docker runtime environment, not on Cloud Run. You must split your docker compose description in multiple services (cloud run, but also Cloud SQL and others)